# Spring Boot Admin server on Cloud Foundry with SimpleDiscoveryClient

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to setup a Spring Boot Admin server on a Cloud foundry. I am using the client [Spring Cloud Discovery](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.3/#spring-cloud-discovery-support) with  SimpleDiscoveryClient configuration. We are not having any Thrid Party service discovery client like eureka. I can see the service getting registered to the spring boot admin server. But when i scale up any service, i see only one instance of that service and the actual number of instances are not reflected. I would like to know if that is possible without Eureka or any other service discovery, if yes how to achieve that without them.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer for this @sagar27? I'm having the same issue or behaviour and I would like to know if it is actually a limitation or not.

Comment: @RandyHector - It was long back and to be honest I don’t exactly remember, I tried some way using the cloud foundry instances id (via vcap) and the instance index. But I remember we eventually ended up using eureka which was somewhat redundant with cloud foundry.